# Consuming SOAP service from Windows Azure Mobile Services

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have a Windows Azure Mobile Service up and running, however, there is a need for that service to consume some data expose through an external SOAP service and store that information in the mobile service database.

I would like to set up a worker in the mobile service, so the calls to the external SOAP service are executed in a fixed period of time.

I've been looking for a solution to this problem, but haven't found anything yet. So any help that would get me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to talk to a SOAP service from your Mobile Service backend. The backend is based on Node.js, and even though there are some Node modules for talking to SOAP services, they are currently not supported in Mobile Services. We are working on a solution that will enable you to use any Node module in your service, but it is not out yet.

If you control the SOAP service and it is written using WCF, you may be able to easily add a REST endpoint to the service with just a few config changes and then consume it from your Mobile Service via plain HTTP requests by using the "request" module.